# How I can get USDT TRC20 token balance with python?

Tags: python, parsing, cryptocurrency, tron

I use the code that the Tron api generates and get a 200 response code ('ok'), but I don't get any information about the balances.

Code

```
import requests
#wallet = 'TWMsYUtqEAPxs7ZXuANkpABqGcixK3XZJD'
url = "https://api.trongrid.io/v1/contracts/TWMsYUtqEAPxs7ZXuANkpABqGcixK3XZJD/tokens"

headers = {"accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Response

```
{
  "data": [],
  "meta": {
    "at": 1676483294906,
    "page_size": 0
  },
  "success": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the API endpoint you used: https://api.trongrid.io/v1/contracts/TWMsYUtqEAPxs7ZXuANkpABqGcixK3XZJD/tokens

Here, I used a different API endpoint and it fixed the problem: https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/account?address=TWMsYUtqEAPxs7ZXuANkpABqGcixK3XZJD&includeToken=true.

```
import requests

contract_address = 'TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t'  # USDT TRC20 contract address
wallet_address = 'TWMsYUtqEAPxs7ZXuANkpABqGcixK3XZJD'  # wallet address

url = f"https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/account?address={wallet_address}&includeToken=true"

headers = {"accept": "application/json"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

data = response.json()

if 'error' in data:
    print(f"Error: {data['error']}")
else:
    usdt_balance = None
    for token in data['trc20token_balances']:
        if token['tokenName'] == 'Tether USD':
            usdt_balance = round(float(token['balance'])*pow(10,-token['tokenDecimal']),6)
            break

    if usdt_balance is not None:
        print(f'USDT TRC20 balance in {wallet_address}: {usdt_balance}')
    else:
        print(f'USDT TRC20 token not found in {wallet_address}')
```

Here is the result:
[USDT TRC20 token balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVqzI.png)

Comment: Where did you find this api?

Comment: you can find it here :)

https://github.com/tronscan/tronscan-frontend/blob/dev2019/document/api.md#4

Comment: Show my balance like this -> "balance":133213571, in the event that my balance is 133.213571 , So how get it with decimal?